# Is there a way to get the amount of days between todays date and date stored in NSDate

Tags: ios

I would like to display the number of days between now and a date I have stored in a NSDate.  Is there a way to get the amount of days between two NSDate objects?????

Comment: check my answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202497/countdown-timer-between-two-dates/25202565#25202565

Answer (score 0):

I have published an open-source class/library to do just this.

Have a look at [RelativeDateDescriptor](https://github.com/MattMcComb/RelativeDateDescriptor), which can be used to obtain the time difference as follows...

```
RelativeDateDescriptor *descriptor = [[RelativeDateDescriptor alloc] initWithPriorDateDescriptionFormat:@"%@ ago" postDateDescriptionFormat:@"in %@"];

// date1: 1st January 2000, 00:00:00
// date2: 6th January 2000, 00:00:00
[descriptor describeDate:date2 relativeTo:date1]; // Returns '5 days ago'
[descriptor describeDate:date1 relativeTo:date2]; // Returns 'in 5 days'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this it is working for me.

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"]; // your date format
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date]; // Today's date
NSString * end = @"2014-08-2312:00:00"; // your date
NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:unitFlags
                                                fromDate:startDate
                                                  toDate:endDate
                                                 options:0];

NSLog(@"%ld Days Left",(long)components.day);
```